# How to set quantity text in bold style in text view from R.plurals.cats in android

Tags: android

I am using Plurals to simplify my code. e.g., I used to have

```
<string name="cat">Cat</string>
<string name="cats">Cats</string>
```

Using Plurals instead of multiple strings, I now have

```
<plurals name="cats">
    <item quantity="<b>%d</b> one">Cat</item>
    <item quantity="<b>%d</b> other">Cats</item>
</plurals>
```

However, I used to retrieve strings to use as in code programmatically . e.g.,

```
    String text = context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.cats, 10);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

I want to set 10 value in bold style 
 but it's not setting bold text does not contain bold text please help me how to archive this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
  <plurals name="cats">
    <item quantity="one"><![CDATA[<b>1</b> cat</b>]]></item>
    <item quantity="other"><![CDATA[<b>%d</b> cats</b>]]></item>
  </plurals>
```

And:

```
String text = context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.cats, 10, 2);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: its crashing it shows null pointer exception  on String text line

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `android:textStyle="bold"` in textview wherever that textview is defined in your XML.